# Deploying Flask app to heroku causes 500 error at create_app()

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I am attempting to deploy an app to heroku that runs fine on my local machine using "Flask run". My app is structured similarly to the microblog flask tutorial with blueprints. When I deploy it and then try to access the website I get this error:

```
TypeError: create_app() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

Here is my __init__.py file:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()
login = LoginManager()
login.login_view = 'auth.login'
login.login_message = 'Please log in to access this page.'
bootstrap = Bootstrap()    
uploadFolder = os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/uploads/companies'


def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

db.init_app(app)
migrate.init_app(app, db)
login.init_app(app)
bootstrap.init_app(app)

from app.errors import bp as errors_bp
app.register_blueprint(errors_bp)
from app.auth import bp as auth_bp
app.register_blueprint(auth_bp, url_prefix="/auth")
from app.main import bp as main_bp
app.register_blueprint(main_bp, url_prefix="/")


if not app.debug and not app.testing:
    if not os.path.exists('logs'):
        os.mkdir('logs')
    file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('logs/StructuredSafety.log', maxBytes=10240,
                                        backupCount=10)
    file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
        '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s [in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d]'))
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    app.logger.info('Structured Safety startup')

return app

from app import models
```

My app.py file is:

```
from app import create_app as application
from app import db
from app.models import User

app = application
```

My Procfile looks like this:

```
web: flask db upgrade; gunicorn StructuredSafety:app
```

I have been struggling to find resources for this issue online. I understand that create_app is being called by my app.py file, but I am not passing anything in there so I am curious where create_app is actually being called from, and why its receiving to many arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call create_app to get the application that Gunicorn will serve.

In `app.py` do:

```
from app import create_app
app = create_app()
```

Then change your Procfile to this:

```
web: flask db upgrade; gunicorn app:app
```

Comment: So that kinda worked. instead of from "StructuredSafety" import app, it should just be "from app import app" because my app folder is named app, not StructuredSafety. Thanks for the help! Any explanation as to why that worked?

Comment: My mistake regarding "StructuredSafety". And I'm not quite sure why this works I just had the very same problem as you, though, and this is what ended up working for me.